# "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"- Angular, HTML, Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm getting an error which reads:
"Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined". I am using Angular. I have Typescript and HTML files. The code is below.

Typescript:

```
public deleteRow(btn) {
    console.log("parentNode:" + btn.parentNode);
    var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<tr bg-color="#2b5dd1" *ngFor="let row of rows; let even = even; let odd = odd" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even}" class = "even">
      <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text1"  tabindex="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text2" tabindex="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text2" tabindex="3"></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" (click)="deleteRow(this)">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

I am not sure what's going wrong, it should work perfectly.
I'm working on putting together a Stackblitz to demonstrate how it works.
Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `this` is the component instance here `deleteRow(this)`

Comment: Which line is that error occurring on? could be one of two.

Comment: @KevinB `var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;`

Comment: You should remove item from `rows`

Comment: or pass `$event` to your click callback, and retrieve the DOM element in your js with `event.target`

Comment: Your current code should work with `(click)="deleteRow($event.target)"` I know it's great to be aware about DOM API but i would advice you using angular approach

Comment: @yurzui Thank you! It's working now! Could you please post as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Consider @bryan60 solution

Comment: Will do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @bryan60's answer is correct and working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keyword this doesn't work like that in Angular templates, you generally won't be accessing the DOM directly, as Angular handles that for you, the idea is you update the model and angular takes care of the view.  Try it like this instead:

```
<tr bg-color="#2b5dd1" *ngFor="let row of rows; let even = even; let odd = odd; let index = index" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even}" class = "even">
  <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text1"  tabindex="1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text2" tabindex="2"></td>
  <td><input type="text" [(contenteditableModel)]="text2" tabindex="3"></td>
  <td class="actions">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" (click)="deleteRow(index)">
  </td>
</tr>

public deleteRow(index) {
    this.rows.splice(index,1);
}
```

working plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/jAHT4CXQcpRgIOxw4eR6?p=preview

Comment: I have solved the issue with @yurzui's comment above.

Comment: that approach will work, but it is inadvisable as it causes your view and model to fall out of sync, ie now your view is different than your model, as you removed the row from the view but not the model. The whole point of Angular is that you don't need to worry about the view, just the model, and angular will keep the view in sync with your model. If you're going to use angular, you should begin doing things the angular way, and your life as a developer will be much easier.

Comment: Oh. I will try your method.

Comment: This does not work. I am not even getting any errors in my console... please advise.

Comment: are you sure you made all of the changes prescribed? and are you using non standard change detection? I made a slight mod to the code to make it a little easier to understand

Comment: make sure to add index to your declarations in ngFor, then change the argument in the deleteRow() call to be index, then modify the deleteRow function. If you do these things correctly it will work

Comment: I have made all of the changes. I am using standard change detection. I struggles trying to get that method to work for about 6 hours and gave up on using that. I had seen that in a similar Stack Overflow post.

Comment: you should post a plunkr. You're probably missing something basic that is causing this to not work, will gladly help with a plunkr because this is a simple pattern that always works and it is worth learning if you want to do angular

Comment: Updated: plnkr.co/edit/2KaXodEe2CbQdLXZtVaC?p=preview

Ignore the fact that the index.html has the template. I tried fixing this but was unsuccessful...

Comment: of course this doesn't work, you haven't even bootstrapped an application, your basic configuration is off, hold on.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time doing a plunkr.

Comment: ok i added a working plunkr to my answer so you can review. Try restarting your project with the CLI if nothing else seems to be working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159257/discussion-between-meena-mana-and-bryan60).

Comment: quick question- I'm trying to code an "Add" button. How do I set it up to actually add a row instead of deleting?

I can open a new question if needed with my code.

Comment: you can open one, but it's the same concept, you just add a new item to the array and angular will update the view.  use this.rows.push({}); but define the item inside push() to be a model for a "blank" row

Comment: I was able to successfully implement both delete and add functionality in the way you suggested. Thank you for your help.